# rEFInd's EFI file removed but computer still boots on

Tags: boot, grub, bootloader, efi, refind

I'm on multiboot *(Ubuntu/LUKS, Win7/VeraCrypt, Win7 unencrypted)* and I installed rEFind to tinker few boot things I slightly broke. I nearly made my stuff and now I want to remove it (or at least make it not boot in first).

It seems to be an easy question, but:

- I tried to manage boot order with efibootmgr to put it last: what is displayed in BIOS setup is ok but rEFInd still boots first.
- I then removed the .efi file from the ESP, and removed the entry with efibootmgr, but it still boots! I have trouble understanding how it can still boot without this file...

I've tried and changed a lots of things, maybe rebooted arround fifty times today, so I don't really know which details I should explain here.

**So, how could I remove rEFInd at boot ? Where could be located its files if they're not int /boot directory ?**

---

**To be a bit contextual:** I was installing a new GPU but it was not working directly (I just had to plug additional power cables but I didn't know, oops), I've come to remove CMOS battery to test, and then, when booting I had a GRUB rescue prompt (nothing is supposed to have been modified on disk, neither GRUB efi, neither its config, so why?), I could still boot Windows via motherboard UEFI boot manager, and... I don't remember how I did to boot my linux... well, it's confused, there was several problems encountred, but I'm now with this rEFInd on my hands.

---

*Motherboard:* MSI H61M-P20 
*BIOS* is up to date 
*Partitions:*

```
    /dev/sda1: /boot
    /dev/sda2: /boot/efi (initially created by Win7 at installation)
    /dev/sda3-4-5: Windows partitions
    /dev/sda6: LUKS container
```

*rEFInd page:* 
https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html